# Tamanho array bidimensional dentro da struct em C

Tags: c, array, struct

Olá. Eu estou fazendo um trabalho que eu leio um txt (o nome do arquivo é passado pelo argv[]) e gero um grafo. Na primeira linha do arquivo são passado dois parâmetros do seguinte modo:
V A
Esses parâmetros são inteiros e tem um significado: V = número de vértices, A = número de arestas. Até aí, beleza, eu consigo pegar esses números. O problema é jogar esses números no tamanho da array bidimensional de floats da struct. Precisa ser algo tipo "adj[numeroVertices][numeroVertices]".

```
typedef struct Grafo{
    int numeroArestas;
    int numeroVertices;
    float **adj;
} Grafo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numVertices, numArestas;

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fscanf(f, " %i %i", &numVertices, &numArestas);

    Grafo g;
    g.numeroArestas = numArestas;
    g.numeroVertices = numVertices;
    // g.adj = ???????
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com C99 podes usar VLA (*Variable Length Arrays*). Mas atencao para nao abusar dos tamanhos!

```
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fscanf(f, "%i%i", &numVertices, &numArestas);
    int adj[numeroVertices][numeroVertices];      // VLA, C99
    // usa adj
```

Se nao podes usar esta funcionalidade, tens que recorrer ao `malloc()` e amigos

```
    int **adj, k;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fscanf(f, "%i%i", &numVertices, &numArestas);

    adj = malloc(numVertices * sizeof *adj);
    if (adj == NULL) /* erro! */;
    for (k = 0; k < numVertices; k++) {
        adj[k] = malloc(numArestas * sizeof **adj);
        if (adj[k] == NULL) /* erro! */;
    }

    /* usa adj como um array */

    /* libertar recursos */
    for (k = 0; k < numVertices; k++) {
        free(adj[k]);
    }
    free(adj);
```

Comment: Valeu! Só uma dúvida: nessa linha "adj[k] = malloc(numArestas * size of **adj)" eu estou fazendo ela ser uma array quadrada? Isto é, se eu passar numVertices = 4, no final do for terei uma array 4x4?

Comment: Podes usar o objecto final como se fosse um array de 4x4 (mas nao é um array verdadeiro). Naquela parte do `/* usa adj como um array */` podes por qualquer coisa assim: `for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) { adj[k][0] = 0.8; adj[k][1] = -3.14; adj[k][2] = adj[k][3] = 0; }`